# Does every maximal almost disjoint family have the same chromatic number?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, graph-colorings, infinite-combinatorics, hypergraph

If $H=(V,E)$ is a [hypergraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph) such that $V\neq\varnothing\neq E$ and $|e| > 1$ for all $e\in E$, and $\kappa\neq\varnothing$ is a cardinal, we say that a map $c:V\to\kappa$ is a *coloring* if the restriction $c\restriction_e: e\to \kappa$ is non-constant for each $e\in E$. We denote by $\chi(H)$ the smallest cardinal $\kappa$ such that there is a coloring $c:V \to \kappa$.

Assume the Axiom of Choice. If ${\cal A, B}$ are infinite [maximal almost disjoint families](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_disjoint_sets) on $\omega$, do we necessarily have $\chi((\omega, {\cal A}))=\chi((\omega,{\cal B}))$?

Comment: If I understand the definitions here, the members of the MAD family are the hyperedges, and the vertices are integers. So clearly there is a coloring in $\aleph_0$ colors, so it's really about asking it you can have a MAD family with finite chromatic number, which to me sounds like that it's impossible.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I think it does happen - in fact, any MAD family can be turned into one with chromatic number $2$. Suppose $\mathfrak{X}\subset\mathcal{P}(\omega)$ is MAD; I claim that the new family $$\mathfrak{X}[2]:=\{\{2a: a\in A\}\cup\{2a+1: a\in A\}: A\in\mathfrak{X}\}$$ is also mad. Suppose $Y\subseteq\omega$ is an infinite set such that $Y\not\in\mathfrak{X}[2]$ but $Y\cap B$ is finite for each $B\in\mathfrak{X}[2]$. One of $Y\cap\{Evens\}$ and $Y\cap\{Odds\}$ is infinite; WLOG, it's the former. Then $\{x: 2x\in Y\}$ is a counterexample to the MADness of $\mathfrak{X}$. Or did I mess up?

Comment: @DominicvanderZypen Well even if I'm right, my comment doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Thanks @AsafKaragila for your comment, I edited the question accordingly to make proper hypergraphs. - Noah thanks for your comments, will read them after walking the kids to school

Comment: I think this paper by Erdos and Shelah may have the answer to your question: https://shelah.logic.at/files/95606/19.pdf

Comment: Right @bof thanks for your addendum,will amend

Comment: It looks like a completely separable mad family can’t have a finite chromatic number: otherwise, there is a color n such that the set X of integers getting that color is in the coideal generated by the family, and by complete separability, X contains a monochromatic member of the mad family.

Comment: @Haim Could you be so kind as to have a look at that Erdos-Shelah paper and tell us whether and how they answer the current Question, perhaps in the form of an Answer?

Comment: @bof I'll hopefully find some time later today or tomorrow to have a closer look at the Erdos-Shelah paper. Regardless of their paper, the following seems like an interesting question to me: does the non-existence of a 2-coloring imply complete separability? the definitions look very close to each other, and a positive answer will imply the equivalence of complete separability, the non-existence of a 2-coloring and the non-existence of a finite coloring.

Comment: @bof It looks like Theorem 1.1 in the Erdos-Shelah paper gives exactly what you said, a mad family that is $(n+1)$-colorable but not $n$-colorable (which also provides a negative answer to my question). I'm still not completely sure what the definition of $n$-separability is, but the construction in their proof obviously gives what we want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A negative answer to the question follows by the proof of Theorem 1.1 in the following paper of Erdős and Shelah, where for every $n<\omega$ they construct a mad family that is $(n+1)$-colorable but not $n$-colorable:

*Erdős, Paul; Shelah, Saharon*, [**Separability properties of almost-disjoint families of sets**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02764666), Isr. J. Math. 12, 207-214 (1972). [ZBL0246.05002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0246.05002).

It should also be noted that a completely separable mad family can't have a finite chromatic number: given any finite coloring, there is a color $n$ such that the set $x$ of integers getting that color belongs to the coideal generated by the mad family. By complete separability, $x$ contains a monochromatic member of the family. I won't be surprised if there are also $ZFC$ constructions of such families, but I haven't thought about it enough.

Comment: Suppose you partition $\omega$ into infinitely many infinite sets $A_n$ and on each $A_n$ you construct a MAD family with chromatic number $n$, then the union will be an AD family with chromatic number $\aleph_0$, and if you extend it to a maximal AD family, the chromatic number won't get any smaller, isn't that right?

Comment: Oops! I corrected the answer now. Yes, the Erdos-Shelah construction is done in ZFC. I didn't read the entire paper, but just going through the statements of the theorems (and keeping in mind that we don't know what n-separability is), it doesn't look like they construct a mad family with an infinite chromatic number (the more I think about it, the less trivial it seems. Even a consistency result would be nice). One of the reasons that I write "mad" is to reflect the fact that we use the Hebrew word for "mad/crazy" when we talk about those families. :)

Comment: And I suppose "mad" families are related somehow to "happy" families, which I've heard of before though I don't remember the definition.

Comment: @bof It looks like your suggested construction works. Indeed, mad families are related to happy families: the coideal corresponding to an infinite almost disjoint family is a happy family. Both terms were introduced by Mathias (though, sadly, he chose to write "MAD" instead of "mad" in his "Happy families" paper).